# 'All Programs' Shortcuts are missing

Tags: windows-7, windows, shortcuts, start-menu

Using Windows 7, when I go to `Start -> All Programs` I can see the full structure and all of the shortcuts, but when I click on one, nothing happens. I navigated to:

> `C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

and the majority of the "All Programs" structure is missing.

I found if I clicked a shortcut under the "All Programs" menu that also existed in the backend "AppData" tree, everything works as expected.

What would cause Windows to place the program shortcut under `Start -> All Programs`, but not create an actual shortcut behind the scenes? Is there a registry entry that determines where these shortcuts are created?

Comment: Did these shortcuts exist at some point and are now missing?

Comment: I'm inclined to say they didn't previously exist. Looking a bit deeper I found the other shortcuts reside under `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu Programs`. These shortcuts work if I use them directly, but not from the "All Programs" menu.

Comment: I have the same issue, try this
http://superuser.com/questions/651262/missing-programs-shortcut-from-all-programs/651282#651282