# Missing programs shortcut from "All programs"

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

When I go to *Start -> All Programs* I cant see all of the default shortcuts.[image]!

I have tried, to customize "everything" on properties in start menu (like search other files and libraries). 
Also in 
`*C:\Users\Adnimistrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs*`
I have only few programs.The one you see on screen, but I have lot more programs in my *C:\Program Files* folder.

Also wnen I search for some of **Windows featurs**, I cannot find them, like **Paint** ( The  content of Accessories folder, is not "normal" as well, because a lot of stuff is missing.
 [image]!

There was alredy [this](https://superuser.com/questions/538264/all-programs-shortcuts-are-missing) question posted on superuser.com, but with no answer.
Also, new programs that I have installed are on the All programs list.

Comment: What do you believe is wrong about that screenshot?  I see two shortcuts in the screenshot.  If you want additional shortcuts in your `Start Menu` just add them to the directory thats all an installer does.

Comment: I dont have windows short cut, as well. (paint, calculator.. ) It is not that I want any custom shortcut ( like adding Eclipse in "all programs")

Comment: Sounds like you should start by installing Eclipse or creating a shortcut by hand in the folder.

Comment: I'm not completely understanding -- paint & calculator would be found under "Accessories". Do they not show if you click on the Accessories folder as shown in the image?  FWIW, although I have Paint etc. under accessories & properly installed, if I search for "Paint" I still get "No items matched your search", yet the program runs from c:\windows\system32\mspaint.exe

Comment: I am going to guess you ran into this issue http://superuser.com/questions/21519/all-start-menu-items-have-disappeared

Comment: @ RAMHOUND. I dont want to add Eclipse, know how to do that! I am saying that I DONT HAVE WINDOWS SHORTCUTS like! ( Calculator, Paint, Remote Desktop.. ) So when I want to run them I have to find calc.exe from  RUN!

Comment: @ Debra, no they dont.

Comment: So what does happen when you click on the Accessories folder?  Are you saying that it doesn't expand to show anything below it?

Comment: Also per Ramhounds suggestion, when you go to "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs" how many items does it have?

Comment: Under accesories, only Command Prompt, Notpead, Run, Explorer.. I will edit question with that picture.

Comment: Under this"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs", only programs that are shown in the all programs list

Comment: The contents are handled by the registry btw so if default tools are missing the your registry is to blame

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution, but this is "**workaround**" ...
I have copied

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

**from other computer**, 
so I have all windows things (like calculator, Sticky notes, Sonud recorder, everything under Accessories, Adnimistrative tools etc.. ) 
Than I have put all shortcuts I need in that folder..

Comment: Post this answer in case someone have same problem, but realy hope that someone will will give the right solution, not just this one.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search shows that this problem happens if your PC is infected with malware. I'd suggest performing a deep scan with your preferred anti-malware software.

To solve this problem, try [SevenForums](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/135246-start-menu-all-programs-windows-7-restore-default-shortcuts.html) exhaustively detailed tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, but that is pretty much the same that I have done. It contains "same" zip file that I take from other computer. But thanks.